# pdfmake API? Is there a list of styles, fonts, capabilities?

Tags: css, html, pdf-generation, pdfmake

I'm using pdfmake.  I want to format a document and they have good examples on github and in their playground but I was wondering if they featured all capabilities therein.  I get the feeling that their may be additional properties like switching fonts, adding different style elements or underlining - things not expressly shared in the examples.  Maybe what you see is what you get and that is all but I went over the github page pretty throughly and did not find a more detailed list of capabilities.  It seems hella similar to html but it doesn't seem to have the same styling capabilities of html/css, if there is something more could someone please point it out.

Comment: I never did find anything but I brute forced it out in the end.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here you go.. At least, uncommented below styles are supported. I tried it myself.

```
['font',
'fontSize',
'bold',
'italics',
'alignment',
'color',
'columnGap',
'fillColor',
'decoration',
'decorationStyle',
'decorationColor',
'background',
'lineHeight'
//'tableCellPadding'
// 'cellBorder',
// 'headerCellBorder',
// 'oddRowCellBorder',
// 'evenRowCellBorder',
// 'tableBorder'
]
```

You could use the above styles, as below.

```
var dd = {
    content: [
        { 
            text: 'This is a header, using header style', 
            style: 'header' 
        }
    ],
    styles: {
        header: {
            fontSize: 18,
            bold: true,
            background: '#ff1'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is ther a way to chage the case of text

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin also as shown below.

```
// margin: [left, top, right, bottom]
{ text: 'sample', margin: [ 5, 2, 10, 20 ] },

// margin: [horizontal, vertical]
{ text: 'another text', margin: [5, 2] },

// margin: equalLeftTopRightBottom
{ text: 'last one', margin: 5 }
```

It is from the docs [Here](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/document-definition-object/margins/).

Answer (score 0):

Update: 27/5/2020 from [Github's anwer](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/1049#issuecomment-319365417)

Extending @Romo 's answer:

```
[
'font',
'fontSize',
'bold',
'italics',
'alignment',
'color',
'columnGap',
'fillColor',
'decoration',
'decorationStyle',
'decorationColor',
'background',
'lineHeight'
'listType' // <=== Added  
]
```

It accepts several options:

> 'none', 'upper-roman', 'circle', 'square'